# App stop working when I click a image

Tags: android, image

I created an activity with radio button On and Off. When the user click on On the image appears and with Off the image disappear. Everything works fine but when the user accidentally click on the image the app will stop working. There is no on-click function with the image. Please see the code below.
XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.Recipe3"
android:onClick="Home"
android:clickable="true">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Beth&apos;s Spicy Oatmeal"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="1/2 cup butter, softened"
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="1 cup packed light brown sugar"
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="1 1/2 cups all-purpose flour"
    android:id="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="3 cups rolled oats"
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="1 teaspoon ground cinnamon"
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:onClick="HomePage" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView23">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton8"
        android:checked="true"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Off"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton9"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:checked="false"
        android:button="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Image"
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup2" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:src="@drawable/beth"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
public class Recipe3 extends ActionBarActivity {
ImageView imageView3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe3);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
               if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton8) {
                imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.radioButton9) {
                imageView3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipe3, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void HomePage(View v){
    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Login.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Comment: Is it solved your problem or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is Android can't find `Home(View view)` method implementation.

As when you click on ImageView there is no any onClick for ImageView so it pass its click event to its Parent View, means to `RelativeLayout` and there is `onClick="Home"` written for Relative Layout but not implementation found in your activity.

So as android can't find `public void Home(View view) method`.

Either remove `android:onClick="Home"` this line from `RelativeLaout` or implement `public void Home(View view)` method in your Activity.